# Отображение ячеек Jupyter Notebook в виде слайдов презентации

Tags: python

Требуется отобразить ячейки в Jupyter Notebook в виде слайдов презентации. К сожалению, не помню точно, кажется в ячейке нужно набирать команду, а потом запускать в соответствии с такой маской:
**!jupyter** **nbconvert** <название файла, который открываем> **--to slides --post serve**. Но постоянно возникает такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не считаю, что тянет на полноценный ответ, поэтому держите комментарием: вот статья-инструкция (на английском, но все предельно понятно) https://medium.com/learning-machine-learning/present-your-data-science-projects-with-jupyter-slides-75f20735eb0f

Answer (score 0):

Иногда не нахожу объяснения в работе jupyter. Сегодня попробовал запустить конструкцию команды которую я указывал в своем вопросе и все получилось)! В браузере открылось новое окно в режиме слайд, вообщем все как надо) Почему же вчера та же самая команда выказывала мне ошибку? Непонятно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]